# System.xml changes not reflecting on adminpanel

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, system.xml, system-config

I am trying to create tabs in magento admin panel but it is not working. I tried running all the commands and cache clear.
Please check if everything is fine with the code
`

```
<system>
    <tab id="mymodule" translate="label" class="a-custom-css-class-to-style-this-tab" sortOrder="10">
        <label>A meaningful label</label>
    </tab>

    <section id="blog" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
        <label>A meaningful section label</label>
        <tab>mymodule</tab>
        <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>A meaningful group label</label>
            <comment>An additional comment helping users to understand the effect when configuring the fields defined in this group.</comment>

            <field id="enable" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" type="select">
                <label>Feature Flag Example</label>
                <comment>This field is an example for a basic yes or no select.</comment>
                <tooltip>Usually these kinds of fields are used to enable or disable a given feature. Other fields might be dependent to this and will only appear if this field is set to yes.</tooltip>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

`

And also created `etc/config.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <blog>
            <general>
                <enable>Yes</enable>
            </general>
        </blog>
    </default>
</config>
```

Please let me know what I am doing or what can be the possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue for the solution that I was missing
`<resource>` node in `<section>`

Hope this answer can help others in case you face in future

Answer (score 1):

I think this might may be helpful for you

https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-a-tab-and-load-grid-in-magento-2-customer-admin-edit-page/

But you can check the directory path, because there is some minor mistake that produce this problem.

Comment: Thanks @rana zain , I found the issue , I was missing <resource> node in <section>.
after focusing on the code I found this